# hive query on cosmos fi-lab SparkTask error

Tags: fiware, filab

I've a problem executing hive query on cosmos fi-lab global instance.

First, the problem is emerged suddenly.
Before lunch my hive query works, after lunch running it I obtain this error.

java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:194)
    at eu.trentorise.DataProcessor.main(DataProcessor.java:72)
2014-12-01 09:57:07,812 FATAL [DataProcessor-main] - Exception executing processor: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask

Some details:

- I'm able to open a JDBC connection to default db successfully
- External table is created successfully.
- the query I run is very simple ( SELECT COUNT(*) from
  HIVE_TABLE_NAME; )

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, the problem is solved after restarting both the Shark server and the Spark cluster where Shark runs. This is a known issue for us, for any reason the Spark cluster consumes all the memory resources and crashes after certain time. Still working on finding the reason.

Comment: Thanks, now everything goes fine